# How to Get Unique Record for each category in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a table called product_type & Product.

```
class Product_type(models.Model):
    product_type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False, unique=True)
    product_type_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = True)
    product_type_description = models.TextField(null = False)
    product_type_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='category')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False, unique=True)
    product_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = True)
    product_info = models.TextField(null = False)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    product_price = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(Product_type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product_status = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = "publish")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False, unique=True)
    brand_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    brand_title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    brand_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'brand/logo/%Y/%m/')
    brand_logo_alt_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
    brand_info = models.TextField(null = False)
    brand_description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, default = '1', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, null=True)
    brand_status = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = "publish")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

in product table I've linked brand table as brand and product_type table as product_type, so suppose I've multiple records for each brand in product table. So I only want 1 record for each brand which has a lowest product_price and that record must match with product_type.

for example:
I want only those product which contains product_type = 'accounting'.
so here is a demo data:
product(model data)

product_id:1,product_name:abc, product_type: accounting, brand:aaa, price:$100

product_id:2,product_name:xyz, product_type: accounting, brand:aaa, price:$50

product_id:3,product_name:bdf, product_type: accounting, brand:bbb, price:$150

product_id:4,product_name:ghf, product_type: other, brand:ccc, price:$150

---

so my query result will be product_id 2,3 because 1,2 have same brand but 2 has the lowest price & 2,3 both have product_type = accounting.

I tried too much but nothing works.

I want your help!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by: ".... only 1 record for each brand_id which have price minimum". Give us examples using sample data. Also show us exactly what you've tried.

Comment: I mean look at the product table I've linked brand table as brand_id, so suppose I've multiple records for each brand in product table so I only want 1 record for each brand_id which has a minimum product_price and that record must match with product_type.

Comment: You may be interested in the [aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: What is the behavior you expect if there exists two products with the same brand, product type, and the same price that happens to be minimum?

Comment: Flux please check question now I've updated it properly

Comment: Suppose in addition to `product_id:2,product_name:xyz, product_type: accounting, brand:aaa, price:$50`, these is another product with the same price, say `product_id:5,product_name:xxx, product_type: accounting, brand:aaa, price:$50`. Which one is the minimum? `2`? `5`? or both?

Comment: no, in this case, only 1 record will come which is decided based on product_id order by asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `models.DecimalField` for product prices. Do not use `models.CharField` for numbers. Change the `product_price` field to `product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)` (Stores $0 to $9999.99).

Then, you can try the following:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Min

Product.objects.filter(
    product_type=my_product_type
).annotate(
    min_brand_price=Min('brand__product_type__product_price')
).filter(
    product_price=F('min_brand_price')
)
```

Other related questions on StackOverflow:

- [How to get only latest record on filter of foreign key django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353695/how-to-get-only-latest-record-on-filter-of-foreign-key-django)
- [Django model get unique foreign key rows based on other column max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252706/django-model-get-unique-foreign-key-rows-based-on-other-column-max-value)